# image deformation in an android project

Tags: android

In my android app, I need to deform the image from one point to the other point.
It should seems like that

[image]

**the origin point A and the B is the new position of A**

the result may like that
[image]

I have try to use the "drawBitmapMesh" function to make it possible, but did not reach, here is the wrap code:

public void warp(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY) {

```
        float ddPull = (endX - startX) * (endX - startX) + (endY - startY) * (endY - startY);
        float dPull = (float) Math.sqrt(ddPull);

        for (int i = 0; i < (COUNTS * 2); i += 2) {
            float dx = orig[i] - startX;
            float dy = orig[i + 1] - startY;
            float dd = dx * dx + dy * dy;
            float d = (float) Math.sqrt(dd);

            // do deformation when the point is in the circle
            if (d < cirR) {
                double e =(cirR * cirR - dd) * (cirR * cirR - dd) / ((cirR * cirR - dd + dPull * dPull) * (cirR * cirR - dd + dPull * dPull));
                double pullX = e * (endX - startX);
                double pullY = e * (endY - startY);

                verts[i] = (float) (orig[i] + pullX);
                verts[i + 1] = (float) (orig[i + 1] + pullY);

            }
        }

        invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I solve it by myself, i use the GPUimage for Android and write a customized filter by GLSL, it works good~!